# MXF Files get currputed through FTP Sending process

Tags: 14.04, ftp, vsftpd, transfer, media

I have written the FTP Script to send the file to the FTP Destination and the Transfer is working totally Good. 
but when i open the mxf file it Just a Black Frame and No media is Playing.

```
FTP SCRIPT:

#!/bin/bash
# Define variables

FOLDER="$1" //incorntab Variable
FILE="$2"   //incrontab variable
echo $FILE >> /tmp/test.log;
echo $FOLDER;
############### FTP CONNECTION START #######################
###########################
HOST="ftp.demo.com"
USER="test"
PASSWORD="test"
###########################

cd $FOLDER
ftp -n -v >> /var/log/ftptransferrtde.log 2>&1 $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
binary
user $USER $PASSWORD
prompt
cd From_FTP
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
############### END OF FTP CONNECTION #######################



#rm -f $FILE
```

I dont understand what is the Issue. can someone Help me please.

thanks

Comment: Are other files transferred without problems? Have you tried to transfer MXF files using another way? What application do you use to play MXF files? According to my experience, VLC and MPlayer are not able to play MXF correctly. So I think this is more likely a problem with playing MXF files than with FTP.